# Flash Cannot compare radiobutton label to a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Why first trace prints out not second one whereas I set label in property panel to "hello"?

```
  public function OnClick(event:MouseEvent) {
            trace(event.target.label.toString());
    if (event.target.label.toString() == "hello") {
        trace("hello");         
    };  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me... atleast with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function radiobutton1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace(event.target.label.toString());
            if (event.target.label.toString() == "hello") {
                trace("comparison works");         
            };  
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:RadioButton label="hello" click="radiobutton1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

the error must be somewhere else

Comment: oops yes I mischief uppercase somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would guess that there is an extra space in the label accidentally.

Try `trace(event.target.label.toString().length);` If it isn't 5, that's you're problem.